# Apple Store will not download apps

Tags: mac-appstore

I cannot download apps from the app store.
I am running Mojave and do not want to upgrade

I have already tried to do the following:

- Sign in and out of my app store account
- Delete any app store cache files
- Kill any app store process and tried again
- Reinstalled Mojave
- Installed from a backup
- Tried to install apps on a different user

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: I don't get any error message, it just spins forever and never downloads.

Comment: I have tried everything in all those other posts, still, the store will not download.